# How to completely remove Nix package manager?

Tags: install, software, macos, open-source

I installed Nix package manager, and now I would like to remove it completely.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2014/07/31/manual-complete-app-removal-mac-os-x-terminal/

Comment: https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/458

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I asked myself the same question and searched the file system for Nix-related files. That's what I found:

```
# as user, remove:
rm -r ~/.nix-channels ~/.nix-defexpr ~/.nix-profile
# as root (sudo), remove:
sudo rm -r /nix
# edit the file ~/.profile and remove the line containing "added by Nix installer"
```

Not sure if I missed some files or directories. Also, I did not remove it myself, so be careful (and backup your data!) when removing stuff with sudo.

Comment: I don't think this would get everything, Doesn't the Nix install create users and run a daemon as well?

Comment: I would never have thought that the package manager can not delete itself normally! Even brew can. I cry. And will never install Nix again.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon Where did you get this info? I don't see any user creation nor daemon. According to the official doc, this answer is correct.

Comment: It's been awhile, so memory is a little hazy and things could have evolved, but when I installed it on my Mac it definitely created users that I later went back and manually deleted. This uninstall script from 2019 also makes reference to users and a daemon, https://gist.github.com/expelledboy/c00aebb004b178cf78b2c9b344526ff6